# connection laravel with mysql container on docker

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

On Docker I already have a Laravel container and Container MySQL, how to connect the MySQL container and container Laravel on Docker?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what docker-compose was made for!

Check out this tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

It's trying to do something similar: connect wordpress to mysql. The key is that both the docker containers defined in docker-compose.yml share the same network - and you can refer to each container by using their logical name. See how the `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST` environment variable is set to `db:3306` - that will resolve to the IP of the `mysql` container within the docker network.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, all containers must run in the same network.

```sh
# create your network
$ docker network create laravel

# start your container and link it to your network
$ docker run -d --network="laravel" --name="mysql01" mysql:8.0

# after your mysql is up and running, connect your second and third container like this
$ docker run -d --network="laravel" --name="latihananakit_web" yourimage:yourtag
$ docker run -d --network="laravel" --name="latihananakit_app" yourimage:yourtag
```

I'd recommend to use `docker-compose` for this scenario, because it makes the whole `docker run`-thing a lot easier.

See here for reference:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/
https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-laravel/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

TL;DR:
Create your `docker-compose.yml` like this (you may change environment-variables or other configuration upon your need):

```
version: '2'

services:
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:latest'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=my_user
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=my_database
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=my_password

  myapp:
    tty: true
    image: bitnami/laravel:5-debian-9
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mariadb
      - DB_USERNAME=my_user
      - DB_DATABASE=my_database
      - DB_PASSWORD=my_password
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
```

And get everything up and running by executing `docker-compose up -d` in the same directory.